# Recieving two values from data attribute one being undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-data

I am trying to link to divs together by linking the data-attribute name with the id but seem to receive an error

```
<div class="pod-container grid_3" data-name="#george">
  <div class="pod">
    <img src="img/example1.png" alt="">
  </div>
</div>

<div id="george">Hello World</div>
```

I'm referencing jQuery 1.8.3 and using the following code to identify the data attribute on the div i click

```
<script>
  $('.pod-container').click(function(){
    var identifyId = $(this).data('name');
    console.log(identifyId);
    //$(identifyId).show();
  });
</script>
```

but when it is logged in the console I get.

```
#george                                    testdoc.html:123 
undefined                                  testdoc.html:123
```

Comment: because the second div has no `data-name` attribute.

Comment: I have changed the class of the parent div to "pod-container" and reflected this in the JavaScript but still receive the same error –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just grab the elements that have the `data-name`. What you're currently doing is targeting just `.pods` which may or may not have `data-name`. With the below code, you're just being specific.

```
$('.pod[data-name]').click(function(){
   var identifyId = $(this).data('name');
   console.log(identifyId);
   //$(identifyId).show();
});
```

Comment: Thanks this works, i'd like to learn how, dosen't using $(this) specify only the element I am clicking on though?

Answer (score 3):

You've got *two* elements with class "pod". One of them has a `data-name` attribute, and one doesn't. Each click will trigger the event handler on **both** elements.

Comment: I have changed the class of the parent div to "pod-container" and reflected this in the JavaScript but still receive the same error

Comment: @navigator that's because it's the parent element that does have the `data-name` attribute, not the child element.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 elements with the pod class and are getting 2 events fire. The inner div does not have a data-name attribute.